# underline cell value when specific characters appear in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to check a condition if the value of QUALITY is `D` or `E` then underline it in grid view. How can I do that in `ItemTemplate`?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TOTAL QUALITY">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("QUALITY").ToString() == "D" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

change Your Design in .aspx file like

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TOTAL QUALITY">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QUALITY")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

in .cs file

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Label Label1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");

        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "QUALITY").ToString().ToUpper() == "D" || DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "QUALITY").ToString().ToUpper() == "E")
        {
            Label1.Style.Add("text-decoration", "underline");
        }
    }
}
```

you can add some more css style to beautify label.